# Fan 4-pin connector

Tags: connector, fan

My laptop's power supply to the fan gave up and I want to reroute it. My plan is to use power from the USB. And I want to make it clean, with connectors instead of soldering (where applicable).

The fan uses a 4-pin connection to regulate the RPM. I have purchased a small controller. However I did not realize there was a difference in size. The fan uses a 6mm 4-pin and the controller a 10mm 4-pin.

I want to purchase the respective male and female headers. I would like to know what they are called so I know what to look for.

[image: Set up]

Comment: This is probably a Molex PicoBlade connector.  The pitch (distance between pins) should be 1.27mm.  But it's hard to make a certain identification from one picture, which is a long shot and an isometric view.

Comment: The pitch for the small one is around 1.25 mm and confirmed that it is indeed PicoBlade.

The pitch of the larger one is 3mm. Any idea how to find the male connector for it?

Comment: The pitch alone is only a partial confirmation.  There are other connector families with 1.27 mm [0.050 inch] pitch.

Comment: Did you make sure that this "fan controller" can power a 12v fan from a 5v power supply?

Answer (score 1):

As @Nick Alexeev said in the comment, it's propably a Molex PicoBlade.

http://uk.farnell.com/molex/53261-0471/wire-board-connector-header-4pos/dp/2411457

Can't be sure only looking at your picture. If it would be me, I would get a plug that fits into your controller since you can see exactly what kind of connector you need from the controllers datsheet and replace the small connector from the fan.
 Soldering wires is not a bad thing either but wires have a habit of breaking off pretty easily. Hot glueing around the solder is a cheap man's trick thats not pretty but works.